# Adding CSS to to when creating a tablecell in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a tablecell in javascript and trying to add a css style that I created but for some reason its not working. I know im close but not sure exactly whats wrong here is my code below: The bold line is where im having the trouble

```
    var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'text';
    el.id = 'textField1';
    **cellLeft.setAttribute("class", "MainTableHeader");**
    cellLeft.appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JUXfc/ must be something else in your code. Post more code, and preferably a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue. Plus define "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the class to your element you should use the `className` property like so:

```
cellLeft.className += "MainTableHeader";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cellLeft.className += "MainTableHeader";
```